# Does Bulk API 2.0 support field mapping?

Tags: bulk-api

Does Bulk API 2.0 support field mapping like old version as per below link?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_mapping.htm

Comment: This notes the difference betwen version V1 and V2. It does not specify about mapping file so I assume its same. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/12/slim-new-bulk-api-v2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No :(

Column headers must be named **exactly** the same as the API name of the fields they target.

External ID relationships can be resolved with a `.` but no SDL file or mapping is possible.